In ARM AMBA buses, are the metal paths bidirectional or unidirectional?
I'm trying to figure out if on-chip busses (for e.g., ARM AMBA) have dedicated metal paths for each direction between the components the bus connects.
Or does the bus use the same metal path to make transfers in both directions?
I'm interested mostly in APB or AHB, but details about any other bus are fine.  The bus lines of interest are the data lines.
The question is more theoretical in nature and focused on how practical is it to use bidirectional signal lines in a design.  Are bidirectional lines ever used?

For common on-die buses like AMBA or AXI, connections are not physically bidirectional. A big reason for this is to make sure there are no undefined drive states. Another reason is that a bus with large and wide-ranging bidir signals makes it more difficult to close timing as clock rates get higher.
RAMs however do use bidirectional I/O for the data port. This is possible because RAMs use 'weak keeper' latch storage cells that are either read out during read, or overdriven during write. The hi-Z indeterminate level condition isn't a problem.
More here: https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/static_random-access_memory
You'll note tha the 'bit lines' (read/write data) are bidirectional.

Yes, while the data flow is bidirectional in AMBA busses, there are separate physical data busses.  Here is a quote from the AMBA APB specification:

The APB protocol has two independent data buses, PRDATA for read data
and PWDATA for write data

There is no guarantee that other bus protocols are similar to AMBA.  You need to look at other bus specifications in detail to see how they are implemented.


how practical is it to use bidirectional signal lines in a design

Inside a chip, bidirectional line access doubles the source- and load-point capacitive loading of the line, and may introduce additional reflections as well. When speed vs. power is at stake - and often it is, unidirectional lines are a win.
